# Recursive Block Matrix Multiplcation

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix-multiplication

Trying to implement block matrix multiplication recursively. It works fine for matrices of 2x2 but increase to sizes such as 4x4 and the answers differ vastly

Result of 3 for loops

```
1.53 0.89 0.53 1.33 
1.75 1.09 0.72 1.17 
1.78 1.43 0.57 1.69 
1.73 1.04 0.62 1.51
```

Result of recursion

```
1.34 1.49 0.30 1.45 
2.02 1.93 0.79 1.30 
2.70 2.75 0.87 2.21 
1.81 1.84 0.59 1.47
```

If the amount of blocks within the matrix is greater than 4 I divide blocks into four larger ones and take the square root to get the new dimension like so then make the 8 recursive calls.

```
void myRecMat(float** MatrixA, float** MatrixB, float** MatrixC, int srA, int scA, int srB, int scB, int srC, int scC, int blocks,int dim){
 if(blocks > 4) 
{ blocks=blocks/4;
      int newDim = dim/2;

        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA,scA,srB,scB,srC,scC,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC,scC,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA,scA,srB,scB+newDim,srC,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC+newDim,scC,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA+newDim,scA,srB,scB,srC+newDim,scC,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC+newDim,scC,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB,scB+newDim,srC+newDim,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);
        myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC, srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB+newDim,srC+newDim,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim); }                   
else
{
 int i,j,k,endR,endC;
 endR=srC+dim;
 endC=scC+dim;


 for(i=srC; i< endR; i++)
        for(j=scC;j< endC;j++)
            for(k=0; k<newDim; k++) 
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];

}
}
```

The sr and sc are for starting row and col. The spacing should be right so I'm honestly out of leads here. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please add your function declaration

Comment: Added the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've compiled and carefully debugged your code. If you only intend to use this function on **matrices of 2^k*2^k**, these 2 modifications will help.

First:

```
for(i=srC; i< endR; i++) {
    for(j=scC;j< endC;j++) {
        for(k=0; k<newDim; k++) 
            /*c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];*/
            c[i][j] += a[i][scA+k] * b[srB+k][j];
    }
}
```

Second:

```
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA,scA,srB,scB,srC,scC,blocks,newDim);
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC,scC,blocks,newDim);
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA,scA,srB,scB+newDim,srC,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim); 
/*myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC+newDim, scC,blocks,newDim);*/
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB+newDim,srC, scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA+newDim,scA,srB,scB,srC+newDim,scC,blocks,newDim);
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB,srC+newDim,scC,blocks,newDim);
/*myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB,scB+newDim,srC+newDim,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);*/
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA+newDim,scA,srB,scB+newDim,srC+newDim,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);
myRecMat(MatrixA,MatrixB,MatrixC,srA+newDim,scA+newDim,srB+newDim,scB+newDim,srC+newDim,scC+newDim,blocks,newDim);
```

Comment: Tested with the mods, it was yay on the first and nay on the second. I made the necessary mod to the second portion. In regards to the first, looks like I required an offset for the row of a and the column of b, hence why the numbers weren't adding up. On the second part, when I bumped the matrices up another power of 2, 8X8, because it worked as shown for 4X4, It only did the corners correctly and the middle portion was off because of the missing commented out portions. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried the modified code again with some larger matrices (8x8, 16x16, randomly generated values), checked results with an online matrix calculator, it works fine for me. I guess there could be something wrong with the row/column definition.

Comment: Shouldn't the k-loop condition be k < dim instead of k < newDim?

Comment: I thought it was a typo, and the compiler would tell OP to correct it

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem here is not as much on the implementation of your method, but on the loss of precision of floating-point operations. Sometimes one may think this imprecision is neglectable, but when we do intense operations over a floating point variable, like your triple nested loop, these imprecisions become significant.

One way to go around this is to scale your floating point numbers so they "lose" their decimal part. That is, for example, if you know your matrix won't have numbers with more than two decimal digits, then multiply them all by 100 and get their integer representation. Then perform the arithmetics on integers (which are precise), and in the end get the floating point representation of the result and divide it by 100.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While true and the thought had crossed my mind, I don't think I would change answer like this whether you chose to multiply the matrices iteratively via 3 for loops or recursively by dividing them up.

Comment: Scaling the floating points is a silly way of going about it, especially when you consider the fact that matrix multiplication is a closed operation in the set Q (assuming the matrix components are also in Q). Better would be to use objects with a numerator / denominator and perform division by scaling the denominator. The end result is no precision loss, which is even better than the losses caused by using floating point values.